# Can the angular momentum have complex expectation value?

Tags: hilbert-space, angular-momentum, operators

I am thinking of:
\begin{equation}
\langle{\psi}|L|{\psi}\rangle
\end{equation}
$\psi$ is a complex function.

Comment: Hint: Is the angular momentum operator self-adjoint?

Comment: No, it should be Hermitian but not self-adjoint... Still, I was thinking of L acting on an $\mathbf{L}^{2}$ function so I guess it should be real...

Comment: @Yepman Why do you say that?  Being an observable, angular momentum should be self-adjoint, not merely Hermitian.

Comment: I said that because I thought that L could be like p (momentum), and, being unbounded, it could have complex expectation values for some functions... But that is obviously not true for $\mathbf{L}^{2}$ wavefunctions. Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Expectation values of observable operators are always real.